# What does a variable to a struct contains?

Tags: c++, variables, types, struct

Say I have this simple program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct teststruct
{
   int n;
   long l;
   string str;
};

int main()
{
   teststruct wc;

   wc.n = 1;
   wc.l = 1.0;
   wc.str = "hello world";

   //cout << wc << endl; // what is wc by itself?
   cout << &wc;  // contains the memory address to the struct?
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand what is in wc? When I declare a struct type with the variable name wc; what is wc? Is it a pointer to a memory address? I've tried to cout the contents, but the code gives me an error. Can you please clarify what is wc

Comment: `cout << &wc` isn't going to produce anything meaningful; you need to `cout` the individual members of `teststruct` `wc`; i.e. `cout << wc.str;`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, `cout << &wc` is going to output address of `wc` to standard output...

Comment: @Griwes: Well, you have the gist.  I'm not a C++ expert; why don't you help the OP out by answering the question he is actually asking, which is "how do I show the contents of this struct?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey it isn't at all clear that OP wants to show the contents of the struct instance.

Answer (score 10):

> what is wc? Is it a pointer to a memory address?

No, it's a lump of storage large enough to contain all of the members of `teststruct`.

In this case, it has *automatic storage*, which means that it lasts as long as the code block that contains it - in this case, until the end of `main()`. The details of where it's stored are implementation specific, but in practise it will usually be stored in a temporary area of the thread's stack (a *stack frame*), created when the function begins and destroyed when the function exits.

The exact details of how the members are located within that storage are also implementation-specific.

> I've tried to cout the contents, but the code gives me an error.

That only works for types that have the `<<` operator overloaded. The standard library does that for all fundamental types and pointers, and for some library types like `std::string`; but if you want support for your own types, then you'll need to supply your own overload, for example:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, teststruct const & t) {
    return s << t.n << ',' << t.l << ',' << t.str;
}

cout << wc << endl; // prints "1,1,hello world"
```

Comment: Thank you, automatic storage was what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

`wc` is instance of type `teststruct` with automatic storage. Every other detail is implementation specific, yet, in most cases, implementations use stack as automatic storage area.

`&wc` is expression of type `teststruct *`, resulting in `wc`'s address.

As for the unasked question (why don't you just ask it?): to output contents of the struct, you have to output its members one by one:

```
cout << wc.n << ", " << wc.l << ", " << wc.str << endl;
```

Yet, there seems to be misconception in your code; `1.0` is literal of type `float`, that is, it's floating point number. Are you sure it's what you want to store in `long` variable? If you want `long` literal, use `1L`.

Comment: Thank you, I think "automatic storage" is the keyword to what I was looking for. I do know how to output the contents of wc, but I just didn't know what the stand alone wc contains

Answer (score 0):

`wc` is an object of type `teststruct` allocated on the stack

Comment: Nope, it's instance with automatic storage - stack is just implementation detail and standard doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Griwes: Yeah, you are right. But do you know any other c++ implementations of the automatic storage?

Comment: Fellas, none of this means squat to the OP.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't. But the question is pretty clear and that's how it should be answered.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, OP asked completely clear question; it's out of scope of this question whether he understands the answers or not.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an instance of `teststruct` as a contiguous region of memory that is used to contain the value of its member variables. When you are printing

```
    cout << &wc;
```

you are outputting the *address* of your variable, that is the location in memory at which it is stored. This is a simplistic answer and likely full of detailed technical error, but the nature and wording of your question suggest that it might paint a useful picture to you.